# Find index of an object in an arrray of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```js
const arr = [ 
    { "-MrUU6N2pi7aCwJoqCzP": { "name": "test", "brand": "test", "id": 1 } }, 
    { "-MrUUB4PcPD5G45NGb-y": { "name": "test2", "brand": "test2", "id": 2 } } 
]
```

How do I find the index of the object with the key "-MrUUB4PcPD5G45NGb-y" for example?

Comment: [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex()` and look at the `Object.keys()` for each object in the array to see if the key you want is in that keys array

```js
const arr = [ 
  {"-MrUU6N2pi7aCwJoqCzP":{"name":"test","brand":"test","id":1}}, 
  {"-MrUUB4PcPD5G45NGb-y":{"name":"test2","brand":"test2","id":2}} 
],

keyWanted = "-MrUUB4PcPD5G45NGb-y",

idx = arr.findIndex(e => Object.keys(e).includes(keyWanted))

console.log('Index =', idx)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ;)